# Connected apps section is missing in my developer account

Tags: connected-apps

Connected app section is missing in my developer account! Is there any permission I should enable to create connected apps in salesforce.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look under **App Setup | Develop | Remote Access** - orgs that still show Remote Access rather than Connected Apps should be updated automatically over the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can try contacting Salesforce to enable it or just create a new one, it should be enabled there.

Answer (score -1):

This is related to Canvas. This is what the [force.com Canvas Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/canvas_framework.pdf) says

Prerequisites

You need the appropriate access and tools to complete the quick start steps.

• Access to a Developer Edition organization.
If you are not already a member of the Force.com developer community, go to http://developer.force.com/join
and follow the instructions for signing up for a Developer Edition organization. Even if you already have Enterprise Edition
or Unlimited Edition, use Developer Edition for developing, staging, and testing your solutions against sample data to
protect your organization’s live data. This is especially true for applications that insert, update, or delete data (as opposed
to simply reading data).

**Force.com Canvas is available in pilot and enabled in all new Developer Edition organizations. If you have an existing Developer Edition organization, and you don’t see the menu item Your Name > App Setup > Canvas App Previewer,
contact salesforce.com.**

Comment: Canvas apps are a subset of Connected Apps, so this is not just about Canvas